# Create a modal dialog box inside a JSP from and perform POST action

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to do renaming of files in a page. I have to perform a GET request on submit of dialog popup for renaming the file. The problem I am facing is, the page has lot of input fields so I cannot submit form everytime I rename a file. The HTML components for file list is generated dynamically. 
Here is the code snippet -

```
<div class="modal fade" id="renameModal" role="dialog">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Rename File</h4>
        </div>
        <div  class="modal-body">
         <div id="renameForm" class="form-group">
     <label  class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="inputFname3">FileName: </label><input id="newFilename" type = "text" name = "newFilename"/>
     <br />         
     <input id="confirm-btn"  class="btn btn-primary" type = "submit" value = "Confirm" name = "ok" style="float: right" />  
     <br />
     </div>      
     </div>         
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /modal -->   
    <%
    String str =AdministrationServlet.fileJson(request, collection).toString();
        String x = request.getParameter("ok");
            if(x!=null && x.equals("Confirm"))
            {
      AdministrationServlet.renameFile(request,collection.getUuid(),"manifest_text", collection);} 
      %>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
              $('button').click(function(){ 
                  var id = this.id;
                    var res = id.substring("rename-btn-".length,id.length); 
                    $('#renameModal').find('#renameForm').append('<input id="myfieldname" type="hidden" name="myfieldname" value="'+res+'" />');
                  var oldfilename = $('#myfieldname').val(); <%--"<%=request.getParameter("myfieldname")%>"; --%>
                  var newfilename = $('#newFilename').val(); <%--"<%=request.getParameter("newFilename")%>";--%>                  
                    $('a[id="'+oldfilename+'"]').text(newfilename); 
 });
              });

  </script>
```

How can I perform renaming of files by doing API calls and not submit form. As the entire div is inside a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should made Ajax Call to a Servlet for renaming file. One more thing, you should keep javascript code away from the jsp into a separate js file and include it jsp page using `<script>` tag.

Comment: sometimes including js in a separate file isn't always the case. In fact, inline js makes your page load faster.

Comment: Agree with few cases,but for best practices